# Checking and increasing java heap

Tags: java, memory, windows-server-2008-r2

So to increase the java memory, I will do this:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx8g
```

What is the maximum I can do for Xmx on a Windows 2008 server machine (64 bit)?

After adding the above to the class path, do I need to restart anything?

How can I check the size via cmd line?

Comment: You could use the JNI Kernal32 class to load available system memory and then allocate off of that amount.

Comment: If you have a running java app, you will need to restart it for the change to take effect.

Comment: oh, okay. It's a third party server tool for creating pdfs, but it runs out of memory for large pdfs. I'm trying to "fix" it

Answer (score 1):

you can set it to what you like but Xmx should not be greater than system physical memory.

"Set the maximum size to a value that is close to the total physical memory on the platform" according to Oracle if you have performance issue and want to change the heap size.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf

in terms of checking it you can use jstat or jmap to check it from command line. Please see link below

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html

Comment: It's inside java jdk folder under bin folder.http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html